# Boolean('false') returns true

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to pass a `string` value to the TypeScript `Boolean` constructor and ever get back anything else than `true`?

These both calls always return `true` where I would expect `false`:

```
const trueOrFalse = Boolean('false')
console.log(trueOrFalse) // true

const trueOrFalse2 = Boolean('0')
console.log(trueOrFalse2) // true
```

[TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBXApgeXgMQIYBsLJgF4YAhEEHZLMACgHIAzXfOgSgChRILkA6HEAHMaCFOmx5kHTuGhwkaTM2QAmIqXKVq9AAxsZ3SvyEiF45StZA)

Comment: When you pass an empty string is should return false.

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/truthy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you accept an empty string?

```
console.log(Boolean('')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Boolean()` function call returns an object with a `valueOf()` method, which you can use to get the real value.

Try:

```
Boolean('false').valueOf()
```

(I can't try it because I am typing this on my phone)

Useful article: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-difference-between-boolean-objects-and-boolean-primitives-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Boolean()` constructor try a custom function.

```
function parseBool(val) { return val === true || val === "true" }
```

This should cover `true`, `'true'`, `false` and `'false'` values. If upper case `'True'` or `'False'` are possible values the function would need to expand to use `toLowerCase()` (and check for null/undefined to avoid doing toLowerCase on a bad value).